# Git: how force push a file to all branches

Tags: git, android-studio

I have a sample android project repository where I create samples for each topics in Android and keep in different Git branches, So that at any time I can switch to the corresponding branch and get sample code for a specific topic.

Basically I have a single Android project in Git, but each branch has different code base. Currently I have some 20+ branches in that.

But there are some configuration files like build.gradle which keeps the library versions , sdk version etc. These files I need to update regardless of any branch.

So, whenever I make a change to this config files , I want it to be pushed to all the branches, overwriting the old config files.

Say, if a library update comes, I update the version in `master` branch and push. But it affects only inn  the master branch.

All the remaining 19 branches will have the old version code. I will have to switch to each branch and merge this config file from master.

Is there any single command  for doing this? So that I update the file in one branch and I can force push it to all other branches?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any single command for doing this? So that I update the file in one branch and I can force push it to all other branches?

No.  Conceptually, the way Git works, this makes no sense: `git push` does not push *files*.  `git push` pushes *commits*.

A commit is a full snapshot of every file.  That is, given some commit hash ID—the hash IDs are the actual names of the commits—you can have Git enumerate every file with its content, frozen forever in time in whatever form it had in the index / staging-area at the time you (or whoever) ran `git commit`.  More usefully, given that same hash ID, you can `git checkout <hash-ID>` and populate your work-tree (and your index / staging-area!) with those files.

Hence, if `build.gradle` exists in a snapshot (i.e., a commit), extracting that commit will get you that `build.gradle` file, in the form it had in that snapshot.  So far, this should all be pretty straightforward and mostly what you want.  So now let's look at what it means to make a new commit.

We already noted that each commit has a hash ID.  These IDs are seemingly random, though in fact they're actually a cryptographic hash of the complete contents of the commit.  They are too difficult for humans to use directly.  So Git provides a way to store the *latest* hash ID of some branch—what Git calls the *tip of the branch*—under a human-readable name, like `master`.

These names store *one* (1) hash ID.  So how can you, or Git, find any *earlier* commit if all you know about is the latest one?  The answer is that each Git commit stores, as part of itself—and this goes into the computation of its own hash ID since it's part of the commit contents—the hash ID of the *previous* tip of the branch.  That is, given some sequence of commits:

```
... <-E  <-F  <-G   <--master
```

(with uppercase letters standing in for the actual hash IDs), you will add a new commit by having Git make a commit `H` whose *parent* is `G`'s hash.  Git then writes the new hash into the name `master` so that `master` points to `H`:

```
... <-E  <-F  <-G  <-H   <--master
```

Since `git push` pushes *commits* (not files), you will need to extract each branch tip, including all of its files, and then construct a new commit to take over as the tip of that branch, with the updated `build.gradle` file:

```
          o--...--o   <--branch1
         /
...--o--o--...--o   <--branch2
      \
       o--...--o   <--branch3
```

becomes:

```
          o--...--o--X   <--branch1
         /
...--o--o--...--o--Y   <--branch2
      \
       o--...--o--Z   <--branch3
```

where `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are new commits added to each branch.  You can now push all of these new commits at once:

```
git push origin branch1 branch2 branch3
```

which will send the new *commits* to the server.  As long as you *avoid* using `--force`, the server's Git will ensure that these commits strictly add on to their branches, so that the *server*'s branches grow in exactly the same way that your own branches grew.

Note that if the underlying file contents (the `build.gradle` file) exactly matches in any two commits, those two commits share the Git object holding those contents.  That means that making dozens (*"some 20+ branches"*) of new commits takes very little space—the actual size of a commit is small as the *files* get shared (this is possible because no Git object can *ever* be changed once it is committed).  Even if the file contents vary, Git objects are highly compressed once they appear in Git's *pack files* (which is how smart-protocol pushes work).

If `build.gradle` really has the same contents in every branch (this seems unlikely to me) you can use a simple script to copy the file from some other branch into each branch and commit:

```
... build the base commit on some branch BR1, then:
for branch in BR2 BR3 BR4 BR5 BR6; do
    git checkout $branch &&
        git checkout BR1 -- build.gradle &&
        git commit --reuse-message=BR1 || break
done
```

This loop checks out each branch tip by name, extracts the `build.gradle` from the tip commit of `BR1`, and commits it, re-using the commit message from that commit.

If the files are (potentially) different but the idea is to apply the same *change* to each:

```
for branch in BR2 BR3 BR4 BR5 BR6; do
    git checkout $branch &&
        git cherry-pick BR1 || break
done
```

This is a bit fancier: we turn whatever was *changed* in the tip of `BR1` into a patch (sort of—Git is smarter about this than the `patch` utility) and apply that to the currently checked out branch, and make a new commit, re-using the commit message as before.  Note that this also works if all the `build.gradle` files are identical.

The `|| break` lines in these shell scripts make the loops terminate early if some part of the process fails.  In this case, you must manually clean up, then restart the loop with whichever branches remain to have a new commit added.